# Reading updated values for Excel

Tags: excel, apache-poi, read-write

I have just started using Apache POI libraries and have this existing Excel file that I want to write and read at the same time. I am wondering whether it is possible for me to read updated values due to the change I make in the code.

For example in my existing Excel file:

Cell A1 : 1

Cell A2 : A1 * 2

I want my program to be able to change the value in cell A1 and get the updated value of cell A2. For example change A1 to `2` and retrieve `4` in Cell A2.

Answer (score -1):

It is Possible . There are many tutorial's available  in net. Please surf it.

See some tutorials:

- https://gist.github.com/madan712/3912272
- http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/code-base/write-excel-file/
- http://java67.blogspot.in/2014/09/how-to-read-write-xlsx-file-in-java-apache-poi-example.html
- http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/